# How to show that this formula is a tautology using resolution?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

> 

I know how to show a CNF formula is a tautology using resolution, I've come across this DNF now and have to show its a tautology, is it the same technique or do I need to change it to a CNF? if so how?

```
             F := (A ∧ B) ∨ (A ∧ ¬B) ∨ (¬A ∧ B) ∨ (¬A ∧ ¬B)
```

Comment: Group the first two and second two terms together.

Comment: You can just use a truth table, and show that $F$ is always True.  I can give answer below if needed

Answer (score 0):

You can consider a truth table for the statement:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 & | & A & \neg A 
\\ \hline B & | & T \lor F \lor F \lor F = T &  F \lor F \lor T \lor F = T
\\ \neg B & | & F \lor T \lor F \lor F = T & F \lor F \lor F \lor T = T
\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks that makes so much sense